# Printing Quadratic Equation with conditions

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, quadratic

For our homework assignment, we are asked to compute the Quadratic Equation and then print it out in the format of `ax^2 + bx + c = 0`.

We have the following conditions for printing it:

- If a is negative, put a minus sign in front
- If b or c is negative, the plus sign should be converted into a minus sign
- If b is 0, do not display that term
- If c is 0, do not display that term
- If a or b is 1, do not display it

I almost have it working, but ran into a few hiccups.

```
QuadraticEquation(a=-1,b=1,c=1)
QuadraticEquation(a=2,b=-3,c=-1)
QuadraticEquation(a=1,b=0,c=25)
QuadraticEquation(a=1.2,b=2.3,c=5.6)
QuadraticEquation(a=9.0,b=-1,c=81.0)
```

The following functions above should be returned as:

```
-x^2 + x + 1.0 = 0
2.0x^2 – 3.0x – 1.0 = 0
x^2 – 25.0 = 0
1.2x^2 + 2.3x + 5.6 = 0
9.0x^2 - x + 81.0 = 0
```

However, mine are being returned as:

```
-x^2 + x + 1.0 = 0
2.0x^2 - 3.0x - 1.0 = 0
x^2 + 25.0 = 0
1.2x^2 + 2.3x + 5.6 = 0
9.0x^2 - 1.0x + 81.0 = 0
```

Does anyone see where I'm messing up?

```
from math import sqrt


class QuadraticEquation(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.__a = float(a)
        if self.__a == 0.0:
            raise ValueError("Coefficient 'a' cannot be 0 in a quadratic equation.")
        self.__b = float(b)
        self.__c = float(c)

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self.__a

    @property
    def b(self):
        return self.__b

    @property
    def c(self):
        return self.__c

    def __str__(self):
        a = self.__a
        b = self.__b
        c = self.__c

        # a
        if a < 0:
            a = '-x^2'
        elif a == 1:
            a = 'x^2'
        else:
            a = '%sx^2' % a

        # b
        if b < 0:
            b = ' - %sx' % (b * -1)
        elif b == 0:
            b = ''
        elif b == 1:
            b = ' + x'
        else:
            b = ' + %sx' % b

        # c
        if c < 0:
            c = ' - %s' % (c * -1)
        elif c == 0:
            c = ''
        else:
            c = ' + %s' % c

        return a + b + c + ' = 0'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    equation1 = QuadraticEquation(a=-1,b=1,c=1)
    equation2 = QuadraticEquation(a=2,b=-3,c=-1)
    equation3 = QuadraticEquation(a=1,b=0,c=25)
    equation4 = QuadraticEquation(a=1.2,b=2.3,c=5.6)
    equation5 = QuadraticEquation(a=9.0,b=-1,c=81.0)
    print(equation1)  # -x^2 + x + 1.0 = 0
    print(equation2)  # 2.0x^2 – 3.0x – 1.0 = 0
    print(equation3)  # x^2 – 25.0 = 0
    print(equation4)  # 1.2x^2 + 2.3x + 5.6 = 0
    print(equation5)  # 9.0x^2 - x + 81.0 = 0
```

Comment: Looks like `QuadraticEquation(a=1,b=0,c=25)` is correctly returning `x^2 + 25.0 = 0` since `25` is not negative, so the only issue is that `QuadraticEquation(a=9.0,b=-1,c=81.0)` is prepending a `1.0`, correct?

Comment: Your outputs are the same? 1.0x and x are the same.

Comment: @spiffman That's correct

Comment: @TheLazyScripter One of the conditions is that if the value is 1.0, do not display that value. In other words, I need to remove that 1.0

Comment: if b < 0:
            b = ' - x'

Comment: Just to state the obvious: the Pythagorean theorem is that given a right triangle with hypothenuse equal to C and two other sides equal to A and B, A^2 + B^2 = C^2... this is not the same as a Quadractic equation so you might want to edit your title.

Comment: @Foon You are right, thank you. I was typing faster than I was thinking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your problem it outputs "- 1.0x" instead of "- x"?
You should correct this part. Your current code will work for b=+1, but not for b=-1, as this case is handled under "b < 0" condition.

I think the better solution is to use new variables for the output. Try this:

```
    # a
    a_out = ''
    if a != 0:
        if a < 0:
            a_out += '-'
        if abs(b) != 1:
            a_out += '%.1fx^2' % abs(a)
        else:
            a_out += 'x^2'

    # b
    b_out = ''
    if b != 0:
        if b < 0:
            b_out += ' - '
        else:
            b_out += ' + '
        if abs(b) != 1:
            b_out += '%.1fx' % abs(b)
        else:
            b_out += 'x'

    # c
    c_out = ''
    if c != 0:
        if c < 0:
            c_out = ' - %.1f' % (-c)
        else:
            c_out = ' + %.1f' % c

    return a_out + b_out + c_out + ' = 0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple issues, and since it's homework I won't give you the answer, but point out the problem :)

```
    # a
    if a < 0:
        a = '-x^2'
    elif a == 1:
        a = 'x^2'
    else:
        a = '%sx^2' % a
```

Here, if `a` is *any negative number*, the first expression will be `-x^2`. This means even if you have a=-20, the result will be `-x^2`.

You have three cases here, a is negative, a is 1, and otherwise. But really there are 4 cases: a is negative and not equal to -1, a is negative and equal to -1, a is positive and equal to 1, or a is positive.